# How to say that some (scientific) fact is not a coincidence?

Tags: phrases, science

I am writing a paper in which I would like to point to fact that some phenomenon is not a mere coincidence (and is relevant from point of view of the theory I work within), and afterwards I explain why it is the case. I was thinking of using something like:

> It is not a coincidence that structures from theorem T have a property
>   P.

But now I have some second thoughts - does it convey the intended meaning? How about:

> There is a reason behind the fact that structures from theorem T have
>   a property P.

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: One can only claim that a phenomenon is general by proving it. Thus, a typical statement is:  << It can be shown that the sum of the interior angles of all triangles is the same (180 degrees). >>

Comment: Not a lot to go on here without more context. Either could work, as could "It is not an accident that ..." That said, based on the information you've provided, I prefer your second option. It speaks positively to *reason* as opposed to negatively to *coincidence* or *accident*. That structures from Theorem T have Property P is probably the inevitable result of the structures from Theorem T, and Theorem T itself, being based in part on the definition of Property P.

Comment: Agree with @EdwinAshworth - maybe: “Further, we can prove that structures from Theorem T must have property P.”

Comment: *There is a reason* is pretty hollow, by itself. Just say *... because...*. In other words, give the reason, instead of asserting that there is a reason. (And if you don't know the reason then you cannot assert that there is one.)

Comment: Structures from theorem T must have a property P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more a question about how to word a segue, rather than how to describe an intrinsic relationship between facts. I mean, for example:

- It is not a coincidence that calculating the area of a square resembles calculating the area of a rectangle, because one is a special case of the other
- It is not a coincidence that sodium reacts similarly to potassium, because they have the same periodic group; that idea was a major conceptual breakthrough in its day

Saying "it's not a coincidence" is a perfectly fine way of saying that there's a connecting principle which you mean to elaborate on. The actual principle might be a new observation, or a bit of reasoning, or a semantic argument, or whatever.  Related turns of phrase include "by a similar argument...", "this also accounts for...", etc.

Comment: Your answer convinced me that the first thought was the best one :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

“*It is not a coincidence that structures from theorem T have a property P.*” seems to be the clearer option. Consider that “*There is a reason* [...]” does not exclude the possibility that coincidence *is* the reason.

Of course, you shouldn’t expect either phrase to be enough, so don’t give up on including that explanation as to why the non-coincidence is the case!

Comment: I am voting this up to offset the anonymous downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how sure you are it was not a coincidence and whether you have evidence to back it up, I suggest...

- Some evidence make us believe that structures from theorem T having a property P is **not a random incident**.
- Our study **demonstrates and proves** that  structures from theorem T have a property P.
- Our findings are **significant enough to make us conclude** that  structures from theorem T have a property P.
- We can **conclude beyond any doubt** that structures from theorem T have a property P.

Comment: I don't think you have read the question correctly.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  From what I read, the OP wants to say that a certain scientific observation seems to be more than a coincidence... that there may be some evidence to back it up.  That's what I understand. I've tried to improve it, though.  Please tell me what you yourself make of it.

Comment: Only your first sentence is to the point. The other three deal with the observation itself, not with its meaning.